# Trying to get function to finish so it can return data in node.js with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to promises in javascript. I am using node.js in my bot. I have a function that makes a request to an API to get information on stocks and uses promises for the request.  I am trying to figure out how to make it so my application will read in all the data before it continues. I have no problem receiving data from API that all works. At the moment when I run the code application continues before function finishes gathering/returning data.

The function that gets information from API with my attempt at promises:

```
day: function(member, stocks){
    var real = [];

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){  
    stockdata.realtime({
        symbols: stocks,
        API_TOKEN: world_token
    })
    .then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        var i =0;
        received = response.symbols_returned;
        response.data.forEach(element => {
            real[i]= element;
            ++i;
        });
        if(received == 0){
        console.log("received zero stocks");
        return;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(member, " had error getting realtime ", Date());
        return;
    });

    resolve(real);

    })

}
```

Inside index.js where main code is:

```
 var data = [];
 var myPromise = stockData.day(member, 'AAPL');
    myPromise.then(function(result){
        data = result;
        console.log("worked: ", data);
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
```

I don't know if I am doing it completely wrong or if I am missing just one step but at the moment this is what my console says when I run the code.

```
ready
worked:  []
popsnipes101  Requested: AAPL  || received: 1 Mon Dec 09 2019 23:03:25 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard 
Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

`stock.realtime` is already returning promise so I dont think you need to again wrap it inside the `new Promise`

Also you are doing an empty return in then so you whenever you resolve the promise, you wouldnt get anything back. You need to return the data which you intend to use further. Simplified version could look like

```
async function day(member, stocks) {

  try {
    const response = await stockdata.realtime({
      symbols: stocks,
      API_TOKEN: world_token
    });

    return response;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(member, " had error getting realtime ", Date());
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to move resolve(real); inside the then block.

```
.then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        var i =0;
        received = response.symbols_returned;
        response.data.forEach(element => {
            real[i]= element;
            ++i;
        });
        if(received == 0){
        console.log("received zero stocks");
        return;
        }

        resolve(real);
    })
```

Comment: I got an error when I made the change saying "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" from the index file

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ajay's answer, It looks like you are calling your `then` and `catch` statements just after your promise return statement.  You want to wait until the promise is returned from the function to get your desired result.  Your structure should looks something like this:

```js
// Defining your promise:
day: function(member, stocks){
    var real = [];

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){  
    stockdata.realtime({
        symbols: stocks,
        API_TOKEN: world_token
    })
  }
}

// Calling your promise:
var myPromise = stockData.day(member, 'AAPL');

// Processing your promise response or failure
myPromise
  .then(response => {
    //console.log(response);
    var i =0;
    received = response.symbols_returned;
    response.data.forEach(element => {
        real[i]= element;
        ++i;
    });
    if(received == 0){
      console.log("received zero stocks");
      return;
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(member, " had error getting realtime ", Date());
    return;
  });
```

Hopefully this works and will set you on the right track.  I highly recommend the [Lynda.com course on async](https://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/JavaScript-Async/794146-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A4%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Apromises%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2) to learn about promises.

Comment: you're missing a } or ) somewhere

Comment: yes i fixed that, i was missing } and } to close the initial declaration of the stockData.day function.  My answer was meant to show you the general structure of how to write and use a promise, and the .then and ,catch statements, not so much to be just copy pasted